# Axios request to Opensearch/Elasticsearch

Tags: javascript, elasticsearch, axios, opensearch, bodybuilder.js

Currently able to `GET` and `POST` to my collection but need the ability for more complicated queries, I am using bodybuilder to structure the request and axios as my client.

However using `POST` doesn't return my specified results instead just the first 10 items in my index and using `GET` I'm unable to send a body for these complicated requests leaving me with `POST`.

I've switched setting my data from `data:data` to `body:data` with the same result.

Currently this is my `POST` which again returns data but NOT my filtered data just the first 10 items of my collection.

Any insight would be appreciated!

```
export function searchQuery(search: string) {
  var body = bodybuilder().query("query_string", "query", search).build();

  const data = JSON.stringify(body);
    
  axios({
    url: `${SEARCH_URL}`,
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: data,
  }).then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
  });
}
```

This is my current log of data:

```
{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"Green"}}}
```

Comment: Please log the `data` to make sure you're sending a correct request to ES.

Comment: Also makes sense to run that logged request against ES manually to ensure it filters the data

Comment: This is my current log of data: `{"query":{"query_string":{"query":"Green"}}}`

Comment: Does it return correct data if you run this query against Elasticsearch directly?

Comment: No, it just returns the first 10 items in my collection

Comment: You can use [Explain API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html) to find out why some document is matching your query. Probably you have "Green" somewhere in your data?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments in the question above, you are getting only the first 10 items in your collection, when you run the query against elasticsearch directly.

This is because elasticsearch by default returns only 10 documents in the search result if no [`size` param](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html) is included in the search query.

If you want to get more than 10 results, you need to modify your search query as

```
{
  "size": 20,             // change this according to your requirement
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "Green"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Adrianwritenow its been a long time ! Can you please accept and upvote the answer, if it helped you resolve your issue. TIA ;-)